# strace command with line num

Tags: debian, strace

I want to use strace command to know the system calls in a file for a particular line numbers for example line 9 in example.c .Does anyone have an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Do something on the previous line which is easily identifiable in the strace output, like for example

```
open ("/line8", O_RDONLY);
```

and similarly something unique on the following line. Then compile with `-O0` to keep the compiler from rearranging these operations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something more heavy duty than `strace`. This would be fairly easy with a debugger like `gdb` (or the curses wrapped version `cgdb`).

You might be able to get something working if your `example.c` is making the systems calls directly. The problem is that there could be a number of levels of calls through libraries between `example.c` and the source that makes the system call.

Comment: Actually I want to know the system calls for the few lines of code in my example.c like fork(),usleep(), printf. I am not able to find a way how i can do this . Is there some way in which we can just use function calls directly from the .c file and know the system call interupts?

Comment: I don't think you really mean system calls. System calls are special functions that allow userspace programs to interact with the kernel. The current list is something like this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html. But also is there a reason you need to use strace? You can use macros to print out the line number (or the line number plus one if the macro is actually the line before what you want to know).